# Prove that the sum $2^0+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ is $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

**Attempt**: In an attempt to find the sum of the series given that $2^{p-1}$ is prime,

$$1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{p-2}+2^{p-1}+(2^p-1)+2(2^p-1)+2^2(2^p-1)+\cdots+2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$$

A teacher grouped elements as follows,

$$(1+2^p-1)+2(1+2^p-1)+2^2(1+2^p-1)+\cdots+2^{p-2}(1+2^p-1)+2^{p-1}$$

**Question**: I am confused a little about the last two terms in the summation above as what I think it should be is as follows,

$$(1+2^p-1)+2(1+2^p-1)+2^2(1+2^p-1)+\cdots+2^{p-2}(1+2^p-1)+2^{p-1}(1+2^p-1)$$

**Edit**:
**Question**: I should get the sum $2^{p−1}(2^p − 1)$, but with the way I wrote it I did not get the sum wanted, but I got $2^p(2^p-1)$ for,

$$(1+2^p-1)+2(1+2^p-1)+2^2(1+2^p-1)+\cdots+2^{p-2}(1+2^p-1)+2^{p-1}(1+2^p-1)$$

**Edit** 2: The only solution to this is that the sum is $2^p(2^p-1)$.

Comment: That looks right. So you can factor $1+2^p-1$ out, which is $2^p$. And then you have a geometric sum to contend with...

Comment: You are correct; it’s probably a typo on the part of the teacher.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: One cannot reconstruct the actual series from the title, but the title nevertheless gives a decent notion of what general kind of question is involved and does not actually **disagree** with the question.

Comment: @Brian exactly you cannot reconstruct the actual series from the series in the title, $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ has an odd prime factor for $p>1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you. I should get the sum $2^{p−1}(2^p − 1)$ back, so I don't think the way I write it will give me back the sum I want, which is $2^{p−1}(2^p − 1)$?

Comment: @Avra: You’re right: it won’t. But that’s good, because the correct sum is $2^p(2^p-1)$, not $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you. That is what I got, but the question asks to prove that the sum indeed $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$.

Comment: @Avra: If you’ve copied the series correctly, that’s an error in the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you. The terms in the sum are exactly the same. I double checked it.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in a small value of $p$, such as $3$ or $5$, where you can write everything out explcitly, do the sums, and see what you get? (The sum as you've written it here really *is* $2^p(2^p-1)$, not $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$, no matter what the question you've been asked says.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grouping method is correct. Your teacher seems to have made a mistake.

From your sum you get
$$(1+2^p-1)+2(1+2^p-1)+2^2(1+2^p-1)+\cdots+2^{p-2}(1+2^p-1)+2^{p-1}(1+2^p-1)$$

which is equal to
$$(2^p)+2(2^p)+2^2(2^p)+\cdots+2^{p-2}(2^p)+2^{p-1}(2^p)=$$
$$2^p(2+2^2+...+2^{p-1})$$

Now, you only have to solve

$$2+2^2+...+2^{p-1}$$

and multiply by $2^p$ and get your answer. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

If I read well you are evaluating the sum
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}2^k + \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}2^k(2^p-1) = 2^p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}2^k = 2^p\frac{1-2^p}{1-2} = 2^p(2^p-1)$$

Comment: Thank you. I got this sum, but this is not the sum required. Please reread the question as I have edited it.